OAC - Displaying Average Count by Month of Year
The dataset I'm working with contains the following relevant columns:

Quote ID
Eff Date
Composite Category

The calculation I'm using is not properly displaying the average count of Quote ID by month of year:
AVG(COUNT(Quote ID) BY MONTH(Eff Date), Composite Category)
Strangely, this is producing the same result as my simple aggregate function:
COUNT(Quote ID)
I simply can't get it to produce an average count of Quote ID by Month of Year spanning multiple years.  Thoughts?
